# Unexpected end of JSON Input while parsing json file read asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node js and using MVC pattern in my project so when I am trying to add products to my cart.json file I am facing the issue

```
routes file

const Product = require('../models/product');
const Cart = require('../models/cart')

exports.postcart = (req,res,next) => {
    const proid = req.params.productcartid
    Product.findbyid(proid).then(function(value) {
        console.log(value.price)    // prints the price correctly so the producted is received as an argument
        Cart.addProduct(proid, value.price)
    })
}
```

Product model

```
  module.exports = class Product {
      // constructor function here 

      save() {
          //saving the products here, works fine
      }

      static findbyid(id) {
          const p = path.join(path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename), 'data', 'products.json') 
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               fs.readFile(p, (err, data) => {
                   const allproducts = JSON.parse(data)
                   const result = allproducts.find(p => p.id === id)
                   return resolve(result)   
               })
          })
      } 
  }
```

Cart model

```
module.exports = class Cart {
static addProduct(id, price) {
    const p=path.join(path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename),
'data','cart.json')
    fs.readFile(p, (error, file) => {
        console.log('sgdf',id);
        let cart = {
            products: [],
            totalPrice: 0
        };
        if(!error) {
            console.log('inside error') //prints in console
            cart = JSON.parse(file);
        }
        console.log('outside error') //does not output this and anything below from here too doesn't prints in the console

        const existingProductIndex = cart.products.findIndex(p => 
p.id === id);
        console.log('dghjhjghfg',existingProductIndex) ////does not output this 
        const existingProduct = 
cart.products[existingProductIndex];
        if(existingProduct) {
            existingProduct.qty += 1;
        }
        else {
            cart.products.push({
                id,
                qty: 1
            });
        }
        cart.totalPrice += Number(price);
        console.log(cart);
        fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(cart), error => {
            if(error) return console.error(error);
        });
    });
}
```

};

cart.js

```
const fs=require('fs')
const path=require('path')
module.exports = class Cart {

static addProduct(id, price) {
    const 
 p=path.join(path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename),
'data','cart.json')
    fs.readFile(p, (error, file) => {
        console.log('sgdf',id);
        let cart = {
            products: [],
            totalPrice: 0
        };
        if(!error) {
            console.log('insdie error')
            console.log(file)
            cart = JSON.parse(file)
        }
        console.log('outside error')

        const existingProductIndex = cart.products.findIndex(p => p.id 
  === id);
        console.log('dghjhjghfg',existingProductIndex)
        const existingProduct = cart.products[existingProductIndex];
        if(existingProduct) {
            existingProduct.qty += 1;
        }
        else {
            cart.products.push({
                id,
                qty: 1
            });
        }
        console.log('adsgfdgfh')
        cart.totalPrice += Number(price);
        console.log(cart);
        fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(cart), error => {
            if(error) return console.error(error);
        });
    });
    }
   };
```

The error i am facing is

```
undefined:1



SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at /Users/ratnabhkumarrai/Desktop/max-project/models/cart.js:15:29
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] 
(internal/fs/read_file_context.js:61:3)
```

In my Cart models when i try to console log and see i find that only my half of the code is executed the console log that i tried below does not get executed....What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Its usually caused by incorrect opening and closing of brackets or parenthesis, making the program expect more content even though the file ends before that.
In you case this is caused by this line:

```
// cart.js 15th line
cart = JSON.parse(file);
```

Because the json loaded is incorrect. I would before parsing it, add a

```
console.log(file);
```

to see what it is loading as a file and thereafter run it through https://jsonlint.com/ to check the json syntax.

Though as the error is in the first line, undefined 1, appears in the error you shared, it is possible that your file is empty

If you want there to be 0 products you must either habdle the case for empty or pass a valid json to your JSON.parse such as

```
// an empty array
[]
// an empty object
{}
```

Comment: well i copy pasted the code of the instructor and still got the issue..the only thing that differs was i try to use Promises in my routes file and he used callback so the issue is in my routes file i guess but still no idea

Comment: Because the issue is there

Comment: As my answer says it is probably empty

Comment: Updated pls have a look !

Comment: I meant cart.json

Comment: Show me that one the file you open

Comment: hey actually m not getting you..ofcos at the beginning cart.json is empty as i have to add products when i click on it

Comment: Hey man there it is, empty string is not valid json, empty array could be either handle the case or modify the json.

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai just remember to mark my question as the answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

I got this fixed by using `writeFileSync` instead of `writeFile`. I was trying to read a file that hadn't been closed yet